# Segue destination types & how to find them in code

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uistoryboard

Can anyone tell me how I can phrase an `if ()` statement to discover if a segue's destination view controller will appear in the Detail Split or in the Master Split?

I want to put the `if()` statement inside my `prepareForSegue:sender:` methods.

**EDIT**

All my detail views that are relevant to this question (at the moment) conform to a protocol and I am currently performing introspection on the destination controller using:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(myProtocol)])...
```

I can see that this would not work if I wanted:

1. To be able to show the same class in either Master or Detail of the splitView from time to time, and at the same time...
2. I only want the if() statement to be true when the view is to be presented in the detail split.

Things like `segue.destinationViewController.navigationController == ...` don't appear to be any use either.

I was hoping that since we need to set "Master Split" or "Detail Split" when we set the segue up... there would be a way to access that information less circuitously.

**SECOND EDIT:**

The way I have this set up with using introspection does "work".  It just doesn't seem very "Object Oriented".  I don't think I should be querying the View Controller at all for this information, I can't see why the VC should know anything about which side of the splitView it will be displayed.  Surely the object that should hold onto this information is the Segue and, as I say, it appears this is being "set" in the storyboard when we select "Detail" or "Master" split.

Maybe it isn't a property of anything, but I can't see how to get at it.

I suppose I could query the destinationViewController in its viewWillAppear to discover which NavigationController it is in after it appears on screen but, again, it seems a bit "hacky".

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a better more abstract and reusable way to do this that I'm not aware of, but here is a suggestion that could help in your specific project that requires just a bit of special knowledge of your specific project.

If you use introspection in your prepare for segue, you can check to see if methods exist by using the responds to approach.

So for example, in typical implementations of a splitview controller (note - not all) the detail view will implement the methods to handle rotation.  So if this is true in your project, you could do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:)]) {
    //do something
}
```

}

You could use this same approach based upon something that was unique but constant in your project related to either the master or detail view.

hope that helps,
be well

Comment: Thanks for the that.  I am using to do stuff with the button and this would work fine.  I am already subclassing all my detail views from a class that adopts a protocol so I am actually doing the same thing but with `conformsToProtocol`.  Because you have to select "Detail Split" or "Master Split" when you set up the segue, I just thought there might be a way to access this more directly.  There may be times when I want to present the same class in either side and introspection would probably not work then.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is a little limited, but most times I've seen `prepareForSegue` used, the `if()` block checks `segue.identifier` to do anything that needs to be done specifically to handle building the new page.  If you set the identifier for all your segues, you could just have code to handle each segue from that controller, and change what the code is depending on if that segue goes to a masterViewController or a detailViewController.  Not really a well automated way, but it'll get the job done.

EDIT: oh geez, that wording is kinda confusing.  If you want me to I can put a code example up, but it'll have to wait until Monday, as I don't have access to a Mac until then.

Comment: Thanks.  I need something more general than this because this is going to be subclassed a lot and I don't want to rely on my naming conventions being that rigid... or my memory...

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, thought I'd just mention it quick tho.

Answer (score 0):

The talk of classes and protocols gave me another idea, but again, not sure if it will work - I wanted to test it before posting, but I'm not going to have the time to test anytime soon.

I think you should be able to create 2 new classes, UIMasterViewController and UIDetailViewController, that are subclasses of just UIViewController.  Then, for each of your actual screens, instead of making them subclasses of UIViewController directly, make them either a UIDetailViewController or UIMasterViewController.  Then, in your `prepareForSegue`,

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:UIMasterViewController])
{
  //do master view specific stuff
}
else if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:UIDetailViewController])
{
  //do detail view stuff here
}
```

This should be a pretty dependable way to tell where your segue is sending you, as long as you can set up the custom view controller classes right.  This still won't solve the first issue noted in the question

> 1. "To be able to show the same class in either Master or Detail of the
>      splitView from time to time, and at the same time..."

This could be overcome by making 2 copies of all of the views you want to be able to show as either or both, then make one a UIMasterViewController and the other a UIDetailViewController - copy-paste should be good for most of the rest.

Let me know if this works - I'm not exactly sure how to set up the controllers off the top of my head, but I'm pretty sure it could be done.  If it can, I can see this being a very useful thing.

Comment: Yes, this would also work.  I was doing this first then but on consideration I thought that using the protocol avoided the need to have duplicates of my subclasses.  It just doesn't seem very Object Oriented. I'll edit the question again for more clarity.  Many thanks for your input, much appreciated again.